# Haskell: Computation "in a monad" -- meaning?

Tags: haskell, monads, computation

In reading about monads, I keep seeing phrases like "computations in the Xyz monad".  What does it mean for a computation to be "in" a certain monad?

I think I have a fair grasp on what monads are about: allowing computations to produce outputs that are usually of some expected type, but can alternatively or additionally convey some other information, such as error status, logging info, state and so on, and allow such computations to be chained.

But I don't get how a computation would be said to be "in" a monad. Does this just refer to a function that produces a monadic result?

**Examples:** (search "computation in")

- http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads
- http://ertes.de/articles/monads.html

Comment: Nowadays I prefer to refer to these as *actions* or *computations*.  If they are produced by a function, you might talk about parametric actions or monadic functions, but the latter term is ambiguous.  It could refer to `a -> m b`, but also to `m (a -> b)`.  Since this last one is used in applicative style I prefer a less ambiguous term.

Comment: Be sure not to miss C. A. McCann's answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, a "computation in a monad" means not just a function returning a monadic result, but such a function used inside a `do` block, or as part of the second argument to `(>>=)`, or anything else equivalent to those. The distinction is relevant to something you said in a comment:

> "Computation" occurs in func f, after val extracted from input monad, and before result is wrapped as monad. I don't see how the computation per se is "in" the monad; it seems conspicuously "out" of the monad.

This isn't a *bad* way to think about it--in fact, `do` notation encourages it because it's a convenient way to look at things--but it does result in a slightly misleading intuition. Nowhere is anything being "extracted" from a monad. To see why, forget about `(>>=)`--it's a composite operation that exists to support `do` notation. The more fundamental definition of a monad are three orthogonal functions:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)
return :: a -> m a
join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

...where `m` is a monad.

Now think about how to implement `(>>=)` with these: starting with arguments of type `m a` and `a -> m b`, your only option is using `fmap` to get something of type `m (m b)`, after which you can use `join` to flatten the nested "layers" to get just `m b`.

In other words, nothing is being taken "out" of the monad--instead, think of the computation as going *deeper* into the monad, with successive steps being collapsed into a single layer of the monad.

Note that the monad laws are also much simpler from this perspective--essentially, they say that when `join` is applied doesn't matter as long as the nesting order is preserved (a form of associativity) and that the monadic layer introduced by `return` does nothing (an identity value for `join`).

Comment: Thanks for this discussion, that produced some headway :-).  At this stage, in reading your discussion, I think I'm stuck on not being clear as to what exactly "THE monad" refers to (something that has layers and depth?), in a scenario that involves possibly multiple functions that each return monadic values, composed with help of fmap and join, and their own monadic results.

Comment: @gwideman: In the strictest sense, "a monad" in Haskell is the mathematical structure described by a type constructor and appropriate implementations of `fmap`, `return`, and `join`, and "the monad" would be the specific type constructor and instance being discussed. In practice, the term is often also abused slightly to refer to the data constructors associated with the type constructor and/or values built with them.

Comment: My conclusion: "Computation in 'the' Xyz Monad" means "computation in functions which return values of type Xyz, with said functions composed together using the fmap/return/join methods of the Xyz Monad instance".

Comment: @gwiderman Take a look at `Free` monads in the package [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html) to see how all monads have a kind of interpretation as "something with layers and depth". [Gabriel Gonzalez has a good explanation of this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html). Note that `Free` monads are not the "one true way" of thinking of monads, instead they have a different universal property—for any monad `m`, there always exists a corresponding free monad `Free m` and a unique function `Free m -> m`.

Answer (score 13):

> Does this just refer to a function that produces a monadic result?

Yes, in short.

---

In long, it's because `Monad` allows you to inject values *into* it (via `return`) but once inside the `Monad` they're stuck. You have to use some function like `evalWriter` or `runCont` which is strictly more specific than `Monad` to get values back "out".

More than that, `Monad` (really, its partner, `Applicative`) is the essence of having a "container" and allowing computations to happen inside of it. That's what `(>>=)` gives you, the ability to do interesting computations "inside" the `Monad`.

So functions like `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` let you compute with and around and inside a `Monad`. Functions like `Monad m => a -> m a` let you inject into the `Monad`. Functions like `m a -> a` would let you "escape" the `Monad` except they don't exist in general (only in specific). So, for conversation's sake we like to talk about functions that have result types like `Monad m => m a` as being "inside the monad".

Comment: Thanks. "For conversation's sake" suggests "in the monad" is just vague figure of speech, but I'm not quite satisfied.

"So funcs like >>= [...] return..."

My trouble: >>= and return chain functions that take non-monadic values and return monadic values: 

(func outputs monadic value) -> (extract enclosed val using >>=) -> (process val in func f) -> (wrap outval in monad).

"Computation" occurs in func f, after val extracted from input monad, and before result is wrapped as monad.  I don't see how the computation per se is "in" the monad; it seems conspicuously "out" of the monad.

Comment: @gwideman something to think about: one of your examples you linked to uses a state monad, which is an example where bind is really composition: it's building a stateful computation to be  finally "run" on some initial state.

Comment: I'd say those are "in the monad" because (1) they never return a bare value for you to get a hold of "outside" and (2) when you bind them with `>>=` you're basically injecting them into the `Monad` and then using `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` to merge the layers back together.

Answer (score 4):

Usually monad stuff is easier to grasp when starting with "collection-like" monads as example. Imagine you calculate the distance of two points:

```
data Point = Point Double Double

distance :: Point -> Point -> Double
distance p1 p2 = undefined
```

Now you may have a certain context. E.g. one of the points may be "illegal" because it is out of some bounds (e.g. on the screen). So you wrap your existing computation in the `Maybe` monad:

```
distance :: Maybe Point -> Maybe Point -> Maybe Double
distance p1 p2 = undefined
```

You have exactly the same computation, but with the additional feature that there may be "no result" (encoded as `Nothing`).

Or you have a have a two groups of "possible" points, and need their mutual distances (e.g. to use later the shortest connection). Then the list monad is your "context":

```
distance :: [Point] -> [Point] -> [Double]
distance p1 p2 = undefined
```

Or the points are entered by a user, which makes the calculation "nondeterministic" (in the sense that you depend on things in the outside world, which may change), then the `IO` monad is your friend:

```
distance :: IO Point -> IO Point -> IO Double
distance p1 p2 = undefined
```

The computation remains always the same, but happens to take place in a certain "context", which adds some useful aspects (failure, multi-value, nondeterminism). You can even combine these contexts (monad transformers).

You may write a definition that unifies the definitions above, and works for *any* monad:

```
 distance :: Monad m => m Point -> m Point -> m Double
 distance p1 p2 = do
     Point x1 y1 <- p1
     Point x2 y2 <- p2
     return $ sqrt ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

That proves that our computation is really **independent** from the actual monad, which leads to formulations as "x is computed in(-side) the y monad".

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't see where this bears on my question.  The two instances where you discuss "in"-ness don't make sense to me, but maybe I missed something.
Specifically:
"So you wrap your existing computation in the maybe monad".  
(a) this computation doesn't calculate distance, it simply returns undefined, so I'm not sure what was being illustrated. 
(b) It doesn't "warp the computation" in a monad, it just specifies that the input and output values are constrained to be of type Maybe, which can perform as a Monad if suitable definitions are included,...

Comment: [cont'd]  though in this example that capability doesn't seem to be used.

"That proves that our computation is really independent from the actual monad, which leads to formulations as "x is computed in(-side) the y monad".  That seems more like a non-sequitur. If the computation is independent of the monad, how does this imply that the computation is inside the monad?

Comment: (a) I was just too lazy to type. I thought you know how to implement this (and the last code block contains an implementation which would work for the specific monads, too) (b) You are working with values wrapped **in** a monad, but as I tried to show this doesn't affect the computation much. This makes the outside monad interchangeable, which makes it in turn necessary to mention it somehow when talking about it. If your calculation were more "hardcoded" towards a certain monad like `Maybe`, you wouldn't bother to stress that fact.

Comment: And I think you are interpreting way too much philosophical implications into this wording...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the links you provided, it seems that a common usage of "computation in" is with regards to a single monadic value. Excerpts:

Gentle introduction - here we run a computation in the SM monad, but the computation is the monadic value:

```
-- run a computation in the SM monad
runSM                   :: S -> SM a -> (a,S)
```

All about monads - *previous computation* refers to a monadic value in the sequence:

> The >> function is a convenience operator that is used to bind a monadic computation that does not require input from the previous computation in the sequence

Understanding monads - here the first *computation* could refer to e.g. `getLine`, a monadic value :

> (binding) gives an intrinsic idea of using the result of a computation in another computation, without requiring a notion of running computations.

So as an analogy, if I say `i = 4 + 2`, then `i` is the value `6`, but it is equally a computation, namely the computation `4 + 2`. It seems the linked pages uses *computation* in this sense - computation as a monadic value - at least some of the time, in which case it makes sense to use the expression "a computation in" the given monad.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Boris. The question was about "computation in the [something] monad", not just "computation in". There are several instances of the former in each of the referenced links.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `IO` monad. A value of type `IO a` is a description of a large (often infinite) number of behaviours where a behaviour is a sequence of IO events (reads, writes, etc). Such a value is called a "computation"; in this case it is a computation in the `IO` monad.

Comment: This is indeed an example of the kind of comment in which I don't understand how the preposition "in" applies.

Comment: Well we need to combine two noun phrases "computation" and "the IO monad". English only has a limited number of prepositions. "Belonging to" might make more sense than "in".